# `fastboot devices` not listing coral dev board

Tags: fastboot, google-coral

I'm trying to flash the coral dev board following the steps at https://coral.withgoogle.com/docs/dev-board/get-started/#flash-the-board.

I have the serial connection working and can run `fastboot 0` in `u-boot` on the board. However, when I run `fastboot devices` on my machine, nothing appears.

I'm on MacOS 10.14.6 with fastboot version 29.0.2-5738569 and have installed the CP210x USB drivers for MacOS.

Comment: Did you try with a different USB-C cable ? Can you also add the dmesg output from your host machine to the question ?

Answer (score 4):

I had the same issue. I tried two USB-C to USB-C cables on my Mac and it was still not recognizing the Coral board.

I was able to get my mac to recognize it by replacing the USB-C to USB-C OTG cable with a USB-C to USB-A cable via a USB-C to USB-A (female) adapter. I'd like to know why a straight usb-c to usb-c cable did not work, but at least I know it was a cable issue for now.

Comment: Bizarrely, this is exactly what happened with me!

Comment: Exactly the same here. I tried 2 x USB-C cables (Apple and aftermarket) and neither worked when direct connected. I tried all 4 USB-C ports as well...

Comment: Same for me as well. I tried multiple USB C cables on all ports and none worked. Luckily I found a USB A male to USB C cable lying around, which worked at first try.

Answer (score 2):

I had the similar problem. Here are my suggestions:

1. **Serial connect** coral dev board, **unplug** dev board power cable, open a terminal on your Mac and run:

`screen /dev/cu.SLAB_USBtoUART 115200`

If the terminal is blank, it means it's working. Wait a couple seconds, go to **2**. If the it shows "No such file" on the bottom, then reinstall the CP210xUSB to UART Bridge Virtual COM Port(VCP) driver for Mac (https://www.silabs.com/products/development-tools/software/usb-to-uart-bridge-vcp-drivers) even you have installed it before.

2. Plug your usb-c power cable to your dev board, run:

`fastboot 0`

If it shows "Configured USB Switch for UFP" and the cursor moves to the next line, then **unplug** your serial connection(USB-micro-B cable), **plug** USB-C cable to Data port(OTG). **Make sure the power cable of your dev board is connected to a 2-3A outlet instead your laptop.**

3. Run the code on your terminal:

`fastboot devices`

You should be able to see something like this:

`1b0741d6f0609912        fastboot`

If not, check your data port usb-c cable connection. And make sure the power cable of the dev board is connected to a 2 - 3A outlet, not your labtop.

Hope this would help!

Answer (score 0):

It might be that your fastboot is not the latest version. Try updating it from [here](https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/platform-tools). Then repeat the steps for fastboot. Maybe your serial console cable was disconnected. Hope this helps.

Answer (score -1):

The problem occurs because after you run `fastboot 0`, but before you run `fastboot devices` you are opening a new terminal window not with `screen`.

Comment: Yep, opening a new terminal window. When I plug the USB-C data cable into my Mac machine, `ioreg` doesn't register any new USB devices as being plugged in. Maybe my machine is just not recognizing the USB connection?

Comment: That could be it; if you have access to another machine give that a try

Comment: also, make sure you have the latest version of fastboot if your mac registered it and it's still not showing up